# Proper way to send Raw XML to Tableau Rest API in C#

Tags: c#, xml, rest, tableau-api

I simply want to send a rest request to Tableau's REST API but for some reason .NET isn't sending the raw XML (although tested and it works using Postman in chrome)

```
var admin = "\hardcoded_admin_user"\"";
var pass = "\hardcoded_pass"\"";

var tableau_signin = String.Format("<tsRequest> <credentials name={0} password={1}> </credentials> <site contentUrl=\"\"/> </tsRequest>", admin, pass);
    //if user is validated make a REST call to Tableau Server
    string endPoint = @"http://server/api/2.0/auth/signin";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    var post = client.PostAsync(endPoint,
           new StringContent(tableau_signin)).Result;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, the content is being sent, but as a string/text and not XML. Is that correct?

Comment: correct Nicarus

Answer (score 0):

Provide Encoding and Content Type in the StringContent.

```
var post = client.PostAsync(endPoint,
           new StringContent(tableau_signin, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")).Result;
```

Comment: I get error 400 bad request when using the XML formatted in the users example. However the actual post example here works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = FormatTextBodyForUserSignIn(userName, password);
var httpContent = new StringContent(user, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
var response = client.PostAsync($"api/{TableauAPIVersion}/auth/signin", httpContent).Result;
```